# Autocomplete attribute does not work with GroceryCrud

Tags: jquery, html, autocomplete, grocery-crud

I tried using w3schools' example of using autocomplete

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_form_autocomplete

I used jquery to alter the form and add autocomplete="on" on the form and on the input fields but It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Submit your form then use `F5` on your keyboard to refresh the form. The form saves the last thing you typed so if you put the first character again it will autocomplete. It is also written in explanation : **Fill in and submit the form, then reload the page, start to fill in the form again - and see how autocomplete works.**

Comment: @ParagJadhav It is related to the issue, I tested the code on the site w3schools to see if there was a problem. The fact is that it works so I explain to him what I have done to be sure that he has tried in the same way. 
If he did not do it like that then it should work, otherwise his problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I think there's something in the framework (grocerycrud) that clears the saved cache that the autocomplete is using. still not working :(